# NULL entry at id field in Phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported the sql from one phpmyadmin db and imported same at another phpmyadmin db.

The create table statement is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `h_stats` (
  `Id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Success` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OutcomeFailure` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ThCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT '0',
  `Count` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The insert sql file also I have exported it as follows

```
INSERT INTO `h_stats` (`Id`, `Category`, `Success`, `Failure`, `ThCount`, `OCount`, `HDate`, `Count`) VALUES
(13, 'Hits', 31303, 8828, 8893, 30372, '2015-04-07', 40151),
```

**Note :**

When I try to insert new rows at the place of id `NULL` value is coming.
Can anyone suggest me what to change in create table statement.

Comment: This works for me with no null values. Where are you seeing the error? Although, `Failure` should be `OutcomeFailure` in your SQL command

Comment: @stu Yes I have corrected it checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the id as primary key and auto-increment .

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `h_stats` (
  `Id` int(11)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Success` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OutcomeFailure` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ThCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT '0',
  `Count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So when you add null for id, the auto-increment will come in to play and set it the next value in insert.

Note that this will enforce you to have unique value for id so while doing insert leave `id` into the insert statement. Something as

```
insert into h_stats (`Category`,`Success` ...) values ( ....);
```

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: @  abhik  the id is getting autoincremented.Thanks